# Display a list Set with primefaces dataTable

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have this problem
I want to display a list Set in a prime-faces dataTable
But I happen to encounter this error

javax.el.propertynotfoundexception:  property ' xxx ' not found on type  java.util.HashSet

Comment: check the getter/setter methods existance in the managed bean. there should be public and should not be static ones.

Answer (score 0):

Set´s are not supported by dataTable. Convert it to a `java.util.ArrayList` in your CDI or ManagedBean.

Comment: Thank you for the idea I made the conversion to java.util.ArrayList at the bean But there is the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList can not be cast to models.Users

In the entity Users is existing Set collection that I want to display in the dataTable

Between Users and Engagements exist a bidirectional relation

I am waiting for your help thank you in advance

Comment: You have changed your entity. Revert the changes and create just an ArrayList for display in your PostConstruct method.